# After angular 16 and devExtreme 23.1 upgrade getting expectation prod mode

Tags: angular, production, devextreme, angular-upgrade

I am facing an issue after angular 16 and devExtreme 23.1 upgrade, on runtime I am getting an error as   "Uncaught exception: Bs is not defined" , and it's only giving exceptions in production mode "ng build --configuration production". In development mode it's working fine "ng build --watch".

Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "ims-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "ng serve --base-href \"/northpoint/\"",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "16.1.6",
    "@angular/common": "16.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "16.1.6",
    "@angular/core": "16.1.6",
    "@angular/forms": "16.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "16.1.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "16.1.6",
    "@angular/router": "16.1.6",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.13.1",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^3.1.11",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^16.1.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^16.1.0",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^16.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^16.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^16.1.0",
    "@portfoliobi/pbi-ng": "^3.3.2",
    "angular-notifier": "^14.0.0",
    "cleanup-dependencies": "0.0.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "devextreme": "23.1.3",
    "devextreme-angular": "23.1.3",
    "devextreme-themebuilder": "23.1.3",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-pipes": "^0.1.5",
    "ngx-quill": "^22.0.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primeng": "^16.0.2",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.6",
    "rollbar": "^2.17.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.5.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "16.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "16.1.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "16.1.6",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.47",
    "ace-builds": "^1.23.0",
    "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.20",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "exceljs": "^3.10.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jasmine": "^4.6.0",
    "jasmine-core": "4.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "7.0.0",
    "jasminewd2": "^2.2.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.5",
    "util": "^0.12.5"
  },
  "alias": {
    "ace/lib/es5-shim": "ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js"
  }
}
```

Tried optimization as false in prod mode to pinpoint the exact issue but didn't work.

Comment: Try building with `NG_BUILD_MANGLE=0 ng build`. This will keep the symbols and help the debugging.